# Aligning words without delimiters?

Tags: vim, alignment, tabular

I'm trying to align words with vim-tabular, but without delimiters between them, like commas or colons. For instance:

```
int   x = 1;
float y = 2;
char  z = 3;
```

What expression do I need to use to align text like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Align on the first word

```
:Tabularize/^\s*\w\+/
```

For more help see: `:h tabular`.

Comment: Thanks. I knew about `\zs`, but why do you escape the `+`  (`\+`)?
Also, using `\zs` adds one extra space than necessary, but I fixed it with `\ze`.

Comment: `+` is escaped in magic (default) mode for Vim's regexes. See `:h magic`. Yes this works with `\ze` (although redundant) instead of `\zs`, but that means you are actually aligning on the first word not what comes after it, but in this case it is a nicer alignment. I have updated my post